# HTML contenteditable binding support in Blazor

Tags: blazor, onchange, contenteditable

Is there any way to enable 2-way binding for elements with `contenteditable` attribute in Blazor? Or at least `@onchange` event support?

Works:

```
<textarea>@myValue</textarea>
<textarea @onchange="@MyChangeHandler">@myValue</textarea>
```

Does not work:

```
<td contenteditable>@myValue</td>
<td contenteditable @onchange="@MyChangeHandler">@myValue</td>
```

Comment: There's no `onChange` event on a `td`: same in JS and Blazor.  You have to wire up your own.  `<textarea contenteditable>@myValue</textarea>` doesn't make sense: it's already editable and comes with an `onchange` event.

Comment: You're right about `<textarea contenteditable>`, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug open of this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9974) and there is no support of bind with content editable. i try EislerDavid answer using JS interop and it works!

Code Sample:

```
document.addEventListener("input", onInput);
function onInput(e) {
 let target = e.target;
 if (target.localName == "div") {
   if (!target.value && !target.__contenteditable) target.__contenteditable = true;
   if (target.__contenteditable) target.value = target.innerText;
 }
}
```

Comment: It's state is *We've moved this issue to the Backlog milestone*, polite speak for it's current not on the stove.

Comment: What is the blazor side code required to use this?

Answer (score -2):

> Is there any way to enable 2-way binding for elements with contenteditable attribute in Blazor? Or at least @onchange event support?

Yes there is, but what does `ChangeEventArgs.Value` return?

This may seem simple, but your example is a happy path.  Consider  more radical/boundary examples:

Here's a valid page:

[image]

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div contenteditable="true">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    Welcome to your new app.
</div>

<div contenteditable="true" class="m-3 p-3 bg-light border border-primary">
    <EditForm Model=this.model>
        Value: <InputText @bind-Value=model.Value />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private DataModel model = new DataModel();

    public class DataModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And this is *valid* editing:

[image]

The first showstopper is that the code between `<tag>` and `</tag>` in a Razor file isn't text, it's a `RenderFragment`.

And if we can solve that, what does `OnChange` return in the edited version above?

I can see using `contenteditable` in the controlled environment of an `InputBase` or similar control.

Comment: It is: read the first line.  The rest points out the pitfalls in trying to actually use it.